# Edit NSData before loading onto UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I want to edit a bit of HTML data (`NSData`) I downloaded using NSURLConnection. I want to load this html data to my webview. However, before I do this I need to edit something in the meta tags in the html data. How can I do this?

EDIT: 
I would like to edit the width of the following tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: You need to specify, what editing do you wish to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert the `NSData` into an `NS(Mutable)String`, make your changes, and feed the string to the web view, or convert back into an `NSData` object first if you prefer.